# How to determine row index using a single print statement?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dataframe

Given the data for the row index to be found as `max_sw` and list is `sw_col`.

I tried this and some other variation, but nothing worked.

```
print(i for i in range(len(sw_col)) if sw_col[i]== max_sw)
```

Comment: Python is a wonderful language where you can fit everything into one line of code.  This isn't always the best course of action, however, as it can make your code unreadable.  Have a read of [Tim Peters, The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) which can be read when you execute `import this`.

Comment: Somebody please help, its a part of assignment!!

Comment: You're using print twice for starters.  My advice is to start off working out how to solve the problem in more than one line of code.  Then, once you understand the problem, you can start to condense it down to just a single line.

Comment: that was a typo.. and I can do it if i had to it inmultiple lines... the problem is that it is a part of assignment!!(to do in one line)  _/\_ please help

Comment: You still have a syntax error due to the colon.  Please read up on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We can only go on what we are given and we cannot tell what is a typo and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

The line you have is almost there.  If you put the generator into a list and use only index position zero, this will give you the correct answer:

```
sw_col = ['a','b','c']
max_sw = 'c'
print([i for i in range(len(sw_col)) if sw_col[i]== max_sw][0])  # prints 2
```

A more concise solution would be to look up the item directly in the list, like so:

```
sw_col = ['a','b','c']
max_sw = 'c'
print(sw_col.index(max_sw))  # prints 2
```

Comment: lol i guess then there is a problem with my system... I have already tried these both and got an error as output...btw thanks for help